# sanitize && build url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it possible, whith beautifulsoup (python), to extract urls absolute instead of relative urls of a web page ?

For example, when I scrap http://bing.com and ask a href links :
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):

It return as well as relative than absolute urls :

```
http://bing.com/?scope=web&FORM=Z9LH
/maps/?FORM=Z9LH3
/news?FORM=Z9LH4
/explore?FORM=Z9LH5
/profile/history?FORM=Z9LH6
http://fr.msn.com/
http://www.office.com?WT.mc_id=O16_BingHP
```

Many thanks.

Comment: @Aonymous, you need to be specific with what  you are parsing, there are hrefs like `javascript:void(0)` on the page so joining that to the base is going to give you a nonsense url, you cannot just find every link and expect it to work

Comment: Yes, it's why I'm looking for a function which make sens to links. Now, I process this with many if else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()` and lambdas.

`urlList = filter(lambda aTag: aTag['href'].startswith('http'), soup('a'))`

should do the trick.

In short, check the whether the 'href' attribute of your links start with the string 'http'.

If you want to recreate absolute URLs from the relatives ones, you can do this:

```
urlThatCurrentlyScraping = 'http://bing.com/something/...'
for link in soup('a'):
  if not link['href'].startswith('http'):
    fixedLinkHref = urlThatCurrentlyScraping + link['href']
  else:
    fixedLinkHref = link['href']
  # do something
```

Comment: I would like to recreate links. Not select only http links :)

Comment: You can try and simply prepend the current url that you are scraping to these relative URLs.

Comment: It's not so easy.
For example, if domain/path is 'http://www.example.com/dirpath/' and relative link is '/test.php', it must return http://www.example.com/test.php. Etc . but if it's not implemented in bs, I'll put 'if else', and list conditions. Thank's

Comment: Well if you are scraping a URL, you must have its original absolute value (the one that starts with an `http://` or `https://`)

Comment: Yes. Stackover trim http in my post.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only match absolute URLs, the simplest way to do it would be to use a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("a[href^=http]")
```

Here `^=` means "starts with".

If you want to locate all the links and make absolute URLs out of relative URLs, use [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
from urlparse import urljoin
# Python 3: from urllib.parse import urljoin

base_url = "http://bing.com"
for link in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
    absolute_url = urljoin(base_url, link["href"])
    print(absolute_url)
```

Note that if the URL is already absolute, `urljoin()` would leave it as is.